# how to do long view in interface bulider?

Tags: iphone

i want to develop 320 * 800 view .in that view lot of button,textviews are there.
but i know how to do it dynamically with scrollview.but any tutorial to do it through
Interface Builder?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you have to do is to drag your view object (from the library) into the collection of objects on the XIB window (where files owner and such is).  You main window is locked at a give size but supplemental views (not shown on the primary window) can be any size and controlled as the Answer 1 indicates.

At run time, you will have to associate the scroll view/supplemental views.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you having problems with? Go to the Size tab (Cmd-3) and set the view height there. When you have filled the first screen, set the Y offset so that you can see the next free part of the view. Why can’t you fill the view programatically?